# Any advantage to dynamic JWTs versus static (pre-generated)

Tags: google-chrome-app, android-pay

In my Packaged App (works offline) I have In-App-Payment objects. I was wondering is there any advantages to generating the JWT for the IAPs on-the-fly?

i.e. currently, I generate the JWT tokens for my IAPs and set the lifespan to be around 4 months (this is to cover the fact that I may forget to regenerate the JWT tokens) so whenever I update the app, (if I remember) I also refresh the IAP tokens.

Aside from poor memory, is there any advantage to calling my server to generate the JWT tokens?

Thanks,
-Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO (unsure if it matters to you):

- <strike>"replay" JWT spec has `iat` to mitigate</strike>
- "spoof"  signature is static

Hth.

---

Update: foot in mouth. [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap)...everything is managed for you. Only section that seems relevant is if you manually manage your digital good/s (create on they fly?).

Comment: Can you elaborate on both?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, just wanted to check.